# JavaFX application UI responsive

Tags: multithreading, javafx, concurrency

Sorry for poor English. I am new in JavaFX. I am writing a JavaFX application with COM port. I send AT command and get response from COM port then initialize some variable. In this controller have 3 method by which initialize 3 variable.

```
   private void findModemPorts() {
       // send 4 AT command then
       // get response & initialize myPort
       myPort = "XXXX";
   }

   private void findNumber() {
       // send 4 AT command then
       // get response & initialize myNumber
       myNumber= "XXXX";
   }

 private void currentBalanc() {
       // send 10 AT command then
       // get response & initialize currentBalance 
        currentBalance ="XXXX";
  }
```

now call this 3 method in a buttonAction event

```
   @FXML
private void handleStartButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    pin = text_field_pin.getText();

    backgroundThread = new Service<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {

                    findModemPorts();
                    findModemPorts();
                    currentBalanc();

                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    };
    backgroundThread.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
            level_oparetor.setText(myOparetor);
            level_number.setText(myNumber);
            level_current_balance.setText(currentBalance);
        }
    });

    backgroundThread.start();
}
```

when run this application complete the full task abut 30 second then 3 level set text in at a time after Succeeded. But I want set text every level after initialize one by one vale. Please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do what @Dvarga said or you can just make use of [`Platform.runLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) which runs your code on the JavaFX application thread.

```
@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {
  findModemPorts();
  Platform.runLater(() -> level_oparetor.setText(myOparetor));
  findModemPorts();
  Platform.runLater(() -> level_number.setText(myNumber));
  currentBalanc();
  Platform.runLater(() -> level_current_balance.setText(currentBalance));
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it faster to run the three AT commands in three different threads to get the responses "paralelly"? I am just curious :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ItachiUchiha

Comment: @DVarga Well that depends on the OP's use case ;)

Answer (score 0):

Call the three method in three different tasks with three different `OnSucceed` handler, therefore the three update will be independent from each other.